# How to load plugins like router,cookies etc on this keyword in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Hi i wanted migrate my whole `vue2` app to `vue3` i'm facing too many errors on `this` keyword

Now the problem is

```
this.$router.push({});

this.$route.params

watch:{
  "$route.path" : function(newVal, oldVal){...}
}
```

i'm not able to overload `$router` on `this` keyword , `this.$router` is undefined in every component why.

Below file shows my router initialization code

**./routes/index.js**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../components/Home.vue';
....
const router = new createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes:[
      {components:Home,name:'home',path:'home'},
      ....
    ]
})
export default router;
```

I have registered router something like this

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from "./routes/index.js"
const app = createApp(App)
          app.use(router)
```

now i have used `this.$router` & `this.$route`  something like this inside Home.vue

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>some more html code ...</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name:'HomeComponent',
   data(){...},
   methods:{
      goToRoute(name){
         this.$route.push({name:name});
      }
   },
   watch:{
       "$route.path" : function(newVal, oldVal){  
           if(condition matches change route)
        }
   }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**Question:** despite of doing `app.use(router)` in **main.js** `this.$router`  is `undefined` in every component, how to make `this.$router` available in every component

Please help me, thanks in advance !!

Comment: You didn't show components. It's unclear if this.$router is used in setup function or options api.

Comment: @EstusFlask i have everywhere options api something like this `export default{name:'componentName',components:{},data(){},created(){}}`  there i'm not able to use `this.$router`

Comment: What is the content of ./routes/index.js" ? What are vue and router versions? Any errors in the console? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Generally there's no such problem, you should be able to use this.$router in options api if you did everything correctly

Comment: @EstusFlask, i will edit my question now

Comment: @EstusFlask there is no error in console except `this.$route` is undefined,  **Edited My Question**

Comment: You'll need to provide a way to reproduce the problem. In its current state it's not, the code that was shown is ok. You may notice that Vue 3's router doc https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript shows exactly the same thing, and it's workable. `app.use(router)` line is responsible for this.$route to be available in options api comps.

Answer (score 1):

In vue 3 / vue-router 4 you will need to [use `useRouter` and `useRoute`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html) in the setup of your components to access the router and route.

```
const router = useRouter();
const route = useRoute();
```

Now you can access the router and routes, without the `this.` and the `$`. E.g. `router.push(...)` and `route.params`.

In the template however, you still have access to $router and $route.

Comment: i know this approach, is there any possibility to make it available on `this` keyword as `this.$router` in component

Comment: You could probably write a plugin for that your self, see: https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html#introduction 
But my advise would be to stick to the convention and migrate all components to vue3, otherwise you're building up technical debt. This may be some (boring) work, but more future proof.